# Looping over nested arrays below keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

Ok, so that title might be a little misleading, but I'm not quite sure what i'm describing, so here goes.

I have the following JSON :

```
{
  "lastModified": 1368517749000,
  "name": "Requiem Paradisum",
  "realm": "Chamber of Aspects",
  "battlegroup": "Misery",
  "level": 25,
  "side": 1,
  "achievementPoints": 1710,
  "emblem": {
    "icon": 126,
    "iconColor": "ffdfa55a",
    "border": 3,
    "borderColor": "ff0f1415",
    "backgroundColor": "ff232323"
  },
  "news": [
    {
      "type": "itemPurchase",
      "character": "Osmoses",
      "timestamp": 1368482100000,
      "itemId": 91781
    },
    {
      "type": "itemLoot",
      "character": "Greenmean",
      "timestamp": 1368477900000,
      "itemId": 87209
    },
    {
      "type": "itemLoot",
      "character": "Greenmean",
      "timestamp": 1368475800000,
      "itemId": 86880
    },
    {
      "type": "itemPurchase",
      "character": "Osmoses",
      "timestamp": 1368475380000,
      "itemId": 91781
    },
    {
      "type": "itemPurchase",
      "character": "Osmoses",
      "timestamp": 1368475380000,
      "itemId": 91779
    },
    {
      "type": "itemPurchase",
      "character": "Osmoses",
      "timestamp": 1368475320000,
      "itemId": 91779
    },
    {
      "type": "playerAchievement",
      "character": "Osmoses",
      "timestamp": 1368470700000,
      "achievement": {
        "id": 6193,
        "title": "Level 90",
        "points": 10,
        "description": "Reach level 90.",
        "rewardItems": [
          {
            "id": 87764,
            "name": "Serpent's Heart Firework",
            "icon": "inv_misc_missilelarge_green",
            "quality": 1,
            "itemLevel": 1,
            "tooltipParams": {

            },
            "stats": [

            ],
            "armor": 0
          }
        ],
        "icon": "achievement_level_90",
        "criteria": [

        ],
        "accountWide": false,
        "factionId": 2
      }
    },
```

Basically i need to loop over everything in "news"  and output it. 
What I can't figure out how to parse it correctly : 
A : without specifying key numbers and
B : when it gets to a key that then contains further keys and further arrays under those keys i'm at a loss. (E.g. the "player achievement" key)
I appreciate I'm probably being a bit newbie here and could quite possibly be on page 1 of "php for dummies" but i swear I've googled it to death!

Comment: is this your complete json ?

Comment: That's from the beginning for the first 6 or so keys, it continues for about another 70 entries which are a mix of the ones I've quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this approach could fit. Be sure your JSON array is properly formatted though.

```
 $test = the_json_array;    
 $array = json_decode($test,true);
  function recursive($array) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) echo $key.":".$value."<br/>";
            else recursive($value);
        }
      }
 recursive($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

SEE [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Dont forget to give second argument as `TRUE` otherwise it will return object

and try something like this

```
 $json         = 'your json'
 $json_array   = json_decode($json,true);

 $news         = $json_array['news'];

foreach($news as $value)
{

     print_r($value);

}
```

I think for your purpose you should have look at [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
  function printResult($item, $key)
  {
     echo "$key holds $item\n";
  }
  array_walk_recursive($news, 'printResult');
```

Comment: have you array_walk_recursive I think it should help you .. It seems that current result is from for loop ?

Comment: Ermm . . . . Not quite sure where to put it, code looks exactly as first snippet above presently.

Comment: Ok, I've removed everything from the "foreach" down and replaced with the "function print"
output fails.

Comment: ohh sorry I have mistyped the function .. check edited answer

Comment: ok great, that's displaying the content. Now I just need to figure out how to map each $key & $item correctly.
So first item **type holds itemPurchase character holds Osmoses timestamp holds 1368482100000 itemId holds 91781**
Something like : 
**$itemtype = $key->type;**

Answer (score 0):

yo need to do `json_decode('your-jason', True)` it will convert your Json string to Array.

[Json_decode for more understanding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

if you don't specify `TRUE` in `jason_decode` function then it will return php object

Hope answer the question. regards

Comment: Here is what I've got so far :
$json = file_get_contents('http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/guild/chamber-of-aspects/requiem%20paradisum?fields=news');
$json = json_decode($json);
$news = $json->news;

Comment: you can `print_r` and see how you are getting output, but yes it looks right what you are doing,